# All the slaves in the Hadoop cluster should be of the same configuration

Tags: hadoop, datanode

In Hadoop is it mandatory that all the slaves in the Hadoop cluster should be of the same configuration?

Comment: I suggest you look into using Apache Ambari for managing Hadoop and its configurations

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop datanode can have different configuration like datanode total memory, datanode mount points etc.

Example:
Datanode1 etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml can be like

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/mount/data1,/mount/data2,/mount/data3</value>
</property>
```

Datanode2 etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml can be like

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/mnt/dt1</value>
 </property>
```

Comment: I feel like the question was asking about the `slaves` file.